create image from list of sparse pixels and colors
I couldn't find any solution to this problem:
given (Nx2) pixels (with repetitions) and (Nx3) RGB colors, create an image.

width = 200
height = 100
n = 100*200

x = np.random.randint(0, width, n)
y = np.random.randint(0, height, n)
pixels = np.stack((x, y)).T

rgb = np.random.randint(0, 255, size=(n, 3))

new_image = np.zeros((height, width, 3), dtype=np.uint8)

new_image[pixels[:, 1], pixels[:, 0]] = rgb


The problem with this code is that some pixels aren't filled and remain 0. I thought to postprocess the image with opencv inpaint
mask = np.ones((height, width), dtype=np.uint8)
mask[pixels[:, 1], pixels[:, 0]] = 0
new_image = cv2.inpaint(new_image, mask, 5, flags=cv2.INPAINT_TELEA)

but it's slow and I don't think this is the right way to go..
PS - my array of pixels is rational (not natural numbers)
Tried interpolating with inpaint

see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78513839/interpolate-between-arbitrary-count-of-points-on-a-2d-plane (particularly the comments)
